# Excel - how to find some exact f(x) = x from measurement graph

Tags: excel, function, graph

I am calculating an dynamic resistance of a diode and I have a lot of measurements and I've created a graph from them. And the question is, how do I find from this graph an exact value of arguments, for example: I want to obtain f(x) value for x=5 where i have measurement for exact value fe. x=10 -> y=213, x=1 y->110, and got a graph curve, but how to find f(5) = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use a preinstalled add-on named **Solver**. You have to activate it as [shown here.](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/solver.html)
Then you have to follow one of the tutorial you can find over the Internet (like [this one](http://www.solver.com/excel-solver-tutorial-step-step-product-mix-example-excel)) without finding min o max but finding the exact value you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial: it will depend on your *interpolation* scheme and Excel does not *expose* the scheme it uses when drawing a graph.

Unless you tell it otherwise, Excel (I think) uses a *Bezier Curve* with 2 control points to perform its graphing.

This interpolation scheme transforms, via some linear algebra, to a *cubic spline* interpolation.

But to use cubic spline interpolation, you need more than two data points.

Since you've only given us two points, the best thing you can do is to interpolate linearly but that will not be what Excel does.

An answer more detailed than this if anything will epitomise the rather broad nature of your question. Do Google any terms that I've used: armed with a bit of time and a good internet connection, you ought to be able to solve this problem adequately.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve